# How to manually set an href with value from variables in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using datepicker and each day, month and year is being saved in a variable, which afterwards I print in a structure that I want.

Here is the jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    alert('alert function');
    var txtFromDate, txtToDate;
  $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      txtFromDate = selected;
      var dt = new Date(selected);
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
      $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
    }
  });
  $("#txtTo").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      txtToDate = selected;
      var dt = new Date(selected);
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
      $("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
    }
  });

  $('.submit-here').click(function() {
    // var link = day_1+month_1+year;
    var date1 = $("#txtFrom").datepicker('getDate'),
        day_1  = date1.getDate(),  
        month_1 = date1.getMonth() + 1,              
        year_1 =  date1.getFullYear();

    var date2 = $("#txtTo").datepicker('getDate'),
        day_2  = date2.getDate(),  
        month_2 = date2.getMonth() + 1,              
        year_2 =  date2.getFullYear(); 

    var where = $('#selection :selected').text();
    var people = $('#people :selected').text();

    console.log('www.lekkeslaap.co.za/akkommodasie-in/'+where+'?q='+where+'&start='+day_1+'+'+month_1+'+'+year_1+'&end='+day_2+'+'+month_2+'+'+year_2+'&pax='+people);

  });   
});
```

[The entire code is in this snippet](https://codepen.io/melodiacapoeira/pen/QpRyXm)

How can I manually set the values of an href to the values a variables that I have when I click on a button?

I tried this:

```
$("a#atributo").attr("href", "www.lekkeslaap.co.za/akkommodasie-in/'+where+'?q='+where+'&start='+day_1+'+'+month_1+'+'+year_1+'&end='+day_2+'+'+month_2+'+'+year_2+'&pax='+people")
```

But when I click on link It looks like the attr is not reading the values as variables but as normal text instead.

I am testing in [this site](http://wordpressdev.burnnotice.co.za/)?

Comment: replace single quotes from `"www.lekkeslaap.co.za/akkommodasie-in/'+where+'?q='+where+'&start='+day_1+'+'+month_1+'+'+year_1+'&end='+day_2+'+'+month_2+'+'+year_2+'&pax='+people")` with double quotes to have dynamic content (or vice versa)

Comment: I did it like this but if I run the page the script does not work.
$("a#atributo").attr('href', "www.lekkeslaap.co.za/akkommodasie-in/"+where+"?q="+where+"&start="+day_1+"+"+month_1+"+"+year_1+"&end="+day_2+"+"+month_2+"+"+year_2+"&pax="+people");

Comment: the last `"` after `people` is extra I guess

Comment: Apologies I figured that. It is corrected now.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is a double link when I generate the url.
http://wordpressdev.burnnotice.co.za/www.lekkeslaap.co.za/akkommodasie-in/Volvo?q=Volvo&start=12+4+2017&end=17+4+2017&pax=5
Idealy, I should not have the :wordpressdev.burnnotice.co.za

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the beginning and end of your strings are open/closed by a matching quotemark.

If you start a string with double quotes, end it with doubles quotes. The same applies to single quotes.

Your string assignment didn't work because you tried to close the string opened with double quotes with a single quote.

Consider the following code:

```
$("a#atributo").attr("href", 
  "www.lekkeslaap.co.za/akkommodasie-in/"
  +where+
  "?q="+where+
  "&start="+day_1+ "+" +month_1+ "+" +year_1+
  '&end=' +day_2+ '+' + month_2+ '+' +year_2+
  '&pax='+people);
```

Each individual string literal is opened and closed with matching quotes. It's useful to decide that you create strings with one of the two, and keep consistent with it.

Comment: did this way just now. However, the script does not read the last variable(people).Here the link that it generates: http://wordpressdev.burnnotice.co.za/www.lekkeslaap.co.za/akkommodasie-in/Volvo?q=Volvo&start=14+4+2017&end=26+4+2017&pax=

Comment: Notice how there is no longer a closing quote after `people`?

Comment: My bad...It was empty because I didnt choose any option. it works.
Did notice the following: when it generates, I see that the before it first gives me to the link of the site url (http://wordpressdev.burnnotice.co.za).
Is there a way I can remove that so that I can see this only:www.lekkeslaap.co.za/akkommodasie-in/Volvo?q=Volvo&start=14+4+2017&end=26+4+2017&pax=

Comment: $("a#atributo").text('-');

Comment: sorry what does that mean?

Comment: It selects the a tag with id `atributo` and sets the text value on it to be a hyphen "-" as requested. Your question did ask how to change the anchor tag text, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140057/discussion-between-wosley-alarico-and-pineda).